# How do I calculate a Smoothed Moving Average on a Python Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, finance, moving-average

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to easily calculate the smoothed moving average. To calculate the simple moving average, you would use something like `df.iloc[:,1].rolling(window=3).mean()` and for the exponential moving average you would use something like `df_T.iloc[:,0].ewm(span=40,adjust=False).mean()`. Is there anything similar that I can do to easily calculate the smoothed moving average?

Comment: I looked at [TA-Lib](https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/), a famous technical indicator, and could not find anything similar. So I will have to implement it myself. Please refer to [this](https://www.newtraderu.com/2021/03/20/smoothed-moving-average-smma/).